# Can I direct Delphi compiler to look for unit files with suffixes other than '.PAS'?

Tags: delphi, file-extension

I'd like to avoid renaming all of existing Pascal (`'*.P'`) and Object/Extended Pascal (`'*.PP'`) units to the Borland's default suffix `'.PAS'` since other tools are depending on them. Compiling units one-by-one specifying full file name works fine, but I've noticed what it renders **B**uild and **M**ake modes to incorrect behaviour - compiler acts as there is no source file present, so it processes neither all dependent units nor modified ones. Please advise.

---

Note: It is not always possible to resort to the `uses Fooes in 'Fooes.p', Bars in 'Bars.p';` syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The file extension is not configurable. An alternative is to create one new source file with the required suffix for each file you have. That is, for each file *x.pp*, create *x.pas*. Give it the following contents:

```
{$include x.pp}
```

Delphi will find the file and compile it, but all the real code will come from the old files.

Comment: What about configuring the IDE to define a [custom Build Tool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Build_Tools) that invokes the Delphi command-line compiler for `.p` and `.pp` files?

Comment: Or use NTFS symlinks.

Comment: You should write an answer demonstrating that, @Remy.

Comment: You should write an answer demonstrating that, @Tondrej.